# Getting around "cast increases required alignment order" message

Tags: c, gcc, arm, alignment

I have some code which looks similar to the following:

```
void somefunc(uint64_t val) {
    uint8_t *p;
    uint8_t *s;

    s = calloc( (max_sa_len + sizeof(uint64_t) - 1) / sizeof(uint64_t), sizeof(uint64_t));
    // s must be 8 byte aligned here
    p = (s + sizeof(uint64_t)); 
    // p must be 8 byte aligned here

    *(uint64_t)*p = hton64(val & 0xffff);
...
}
```

And when I compile I get:

```
file.c:400:10: error: cast increases required alignment of target type [-Werror=cast-align]
```

Is there a clean way to get around this warning?   `s`, and therefore `p` *must* be aligned to 64 bit addresses, this it's not a real error.  I tried adding a `p=__builtin_assume_alinged(p,8);` to the code but it did not fix the error. 
I'm getting this error with an arm32 (v7) gcc cross compiler, v 4.7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
uint64_t *s_u64 = calloc( (max_sa_len + sizeof(uint64_t) - 1) / sizeof(uint64_t), 
    sizeof(uint64_t));
s = s_u64; // if you need to address by byte as well 
...
s_u64[1] = hton64(val & 0xffff);
```

Comment: I think you mean `uint64_t* s_u64 = ...` (missing *).